# Get first login of the day

Tags: c#, wmic

I want to create a small console app that will have a countdown timer.
I need to know the time stamp of my first logon onto Windows.

How can I do so? 
I found out that I can use WMIC as such:

`wmic netlogin get lastlogon` in order to receive the last logon time but I want the first logon of the day.

Comment: Try searching the event logs

Answer (score 1):

If you have sufficient permission you can use the System.Diagnostics.EventLog class.

Logon events are stored in the Security log, with EventId = 4624 (note in the .Net class EventId is now deprecated & InstanceId should be used.

You can get the full list of log entries with the following code :

```
using System.Diagnostics;
....
....
EventLog eventLogItem = new EventLog("Security");
```

You can query the log & extract just logon ons as follows :

```
var sev = eventLogItem.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Where(ev => (ev.InstanceId == 4624));
```

You may be able to limit this to just the user you want with something like :

```
var sev = eventLogItem.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Where(ev => (ev.InstanceId == 4624) 
   && (ev.Message.Contains(@"username")));
```

if you examine the message you may be able to improve the filtering. You can then order by the time generated & select the earliest for the day.